Which batch of data is training in keras model.fit() to find outliers
I'm new to machine learning, and trying keras for first time. I am applying a 3DCNN network for custom dataset. The batch loss curve shows there are some outliers in my dataset since there are periodic peaks but I can't figure out the outliers by check each data with my naked eyes (these data all look good in human eye). Is there any way to locate which batch of data is feed to the model so that I can find the outliers by its batch loss? Part of my code as follows:
# Define data loaders. X_train is np array of shape (500, 300,300,300) since my single data is volume, shape(300,300,300)
train_loader = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
validation_loader = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_val, y_val))
# test_loader = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test, y_test))

batch_size = 4
# Preprocess data on the fly during training. ("train_preprocessing" only expands one dim to fit the model input)
train_dataset = (
    train_loader.shuffle(len(X_train),seed=rd,reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
    .map(train_preprocessing)  
    .batch(batch_size)
    .prefetch(4)
)

# Train
model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=validation_dataset,
    epochs=epochs,
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=2,
    callbacks=[checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb, batch_loss_recording_cb],
    workers=1,
    use_multiprocessing=False
)

My goal is for example, know the index (in "X_train") of the training batch, or anything that I can know which batch of data is used. If there are other techniques to find outliers is also helpful!
